# How to get path from user during first run and use that in subsequent run in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am writing a batch program to get a path from user during first run and save it in text file. In subsequent run of batch, the program should take input from the text file.

```
if Not Exist syncPath.txt (
set /p $syncPath=Enter sync folder path:
echo %$syncPath%>syncPath.txt
set /p var= <syncPath.txt
My remaining code goes here.... 
)
else (
set /p var= <syncPath.txt
the remaining code.....
)
```

Without if loop, the path gets stored in to file and i can access that path.

But whenever i put if loop, "Echo is on/Off" this gets stored in my text file. So that i am not able to get user data
If i run without if loop its running fine.

Help me in this stuff.

Comment: The key is [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) as you are writing *and* reading the variable `$syncPath` within the same (parenthesised) block of code...

Answer (score 0):

```
if Not Exist syncPath.txt (
 set /p $syncPath=Enter sync folder path:
) else set /p var= <syncPath.txt

echo %$syncPath%>syncPath.txt
the remaining code.....
```

This avoids the `delayedexpansion` requirement. If the file is missing, request the path. Otherwise read it  and save it regardless.

BTW - `)` and `else` (and following `(` if used) must all be on the same physical line.